# Modifying the existing "project properties" window in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am writing an Eclipse plugin for which I require need to take as input several parameters from the user. I am planning to add these parameter in already existing "Project Properties" window of Eclipse. Is there any way we can do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [ask]. Could you give us the code that you have, what you're expecting, and what you're seeing instead?

Comment: Read about the `org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages` extension point in the Eclipse help